# jQuery if div contains multiple text strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I had a quick script to search for some text (a unique code) in a div and hide a different element if it exists:

```
var itemCode = ["000001"];

if( $(".itemCode").text().indexOf(itemCode) >= 0) {
  $(".codeBox").addClass("hideElement");
}
```

however I wanted to expand this so it finds one of multiple texts (codes) and if any of them exist then hide the element:

```
var itemCode = ["000001", "000003", "000008"];

if( $(".itemCode").text().indexOf(itemCode) >= 0) {
  $(".codeBox").addClass("hideElement");
}
```

and this isn't working. I'm sure It's probably something simple and I'm supposed to add a .each() somewhere but I'm just not getting it working when I experiment trying things, what am I missing?

Comment: `if (itemCode.length >= 0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be slighty quicker if you have a few item codes in your array

```
var itemCode = ["000001", "000003", "000008"];
var regExpPattern = itemCode.join('|');
if($(".itemCode").text().match(new RegExp(regExpPattern, 'i'))) {
 $(".codeBox").addClass("hideElement");
}
});
```

Comment: This worked great thanks, could you explain the .join('|') part please so I can understand how it's working? Thanks again

Comment: The join function joins an array of strings into one string using an optional divider in this case "|". The pipe is used like an or operator within regular expressions. So thisvalue|orthisone. https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp

Comment: Thanks this has helped a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

[`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) takes only one (mandatory) argument, so you'll have to iterate over your list to find element(s) matching your condition :

```
var itemCode = ["000001", "000003", "000008"];

var contains = itemCode.some(function(code) {
  return $(".itemCode").text().indexOf(code) >= 0;
});

if (contains) {
  $(".codeBox").addClass("hideElement");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the further explanation of indexOf, this also worked